# How do I distinct a full row based on a value in the column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Sample data has two tables:

```
Verify 1                                    Train 2
print_id     verifydate     score          print_id     traindate   segments
416         09-mar-17   99                 416           26-jul-16     2
522         09-mar-17   93                 522           26-jul-16     5
854         09-mar-17   88                 854           07-SEP-16     1
854         09-mar-17   91                 854           07-SEP-16     2
860         09-mar-17   85                 860           21-jul-16     1
864         09-mar-17   96                 864           06-SEP-16     3
864         09-mar-17   96                 864           10-SEP-16     4
```

All `print_id` in `Verify` will be in `Train`. I want my result to display each occurrence of `print_id' from`Verify`with the respective`verifydate`and`score`, and then for the same`print_id`to show its respective information from`Train`with the`max(segments)`and`traindate`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Verify.PRINT_ID,
  MAX(Train.TOTAL_SEGMENTS) OVER (PARTITION BY Verify.PRINT_ID) AS segments,
  TRUNC(Train."TIMESTAMP")     AS traindate,     
  TRUNC(Verify."TIMESTAMP")     AS verifydate,
  Verify.Score
FROM Train INNER JOIN Verify ON Train.PRINT_ID  = Verify.PRINT_ID
WHERE TRUNC(Verify."TIMESTAMP") = '09-mar-2017' 
ORDER BY Verify.PRINT_ID
```

However, this is a sample of the actual result that duplicates my print_id giving the below result:

```
print_id   segments   date2      date1        score   
416           2       26-JUL-16  09-MAR-17    99  
522           5       26-JUL-16  09-MAR-17    93  
854           2       07-SEP-16  09-MAR-17    88  
854           2       07-SEP-16  09-MAR-17    91
860           1       21-JUL-17  09-MAR-17    85
864           4       06-SEP-16  09-MAR-17    96
864           4       10-SEP-16  09-MAR-17    96
```

As you notice, my `over(partition by ---)` part displays each `verify.print_id` but the maximum segment value each time. How can I simplify this so that the result I get looks like this instead:

`print_id   segments        traindate    verifydate    score

    416           2       26-JUL-16       09-MAR-17      99
    522           5       26-JUL-16       09-MAR-17      93
    854           2       07-SEP-16       09-MAR-17      91
    860           1       21-JUL-16       09-MAR-17      85
    864           4       10-SEP-16       09-MAR-17      96`

Also, table names have been slightly altered due to work restrictions but I am hoping that should not change the general idea. I am also working on Version 3.0.04 on Oracle SQL Developer. The above query runs okay without any problems, just that some of the resulting data is unnecessary.

A couple of examples that have been kindly advised below generate error: 
`ORA-00904: "XXX_XXXXX_XXX"."XXX_XXXXXXX_XXXXX"."PRINT_ID": invalid identifier
    00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
    *Cause:
    *Action:
    Error at Line:  Column:`
I have checked and double checked the data, the logic, the spellings but cannot work out what I am doing wrong.
Please note that I am a novice at SQL/Oracle as well as this forum, hence I sincerely apologise for any lack of information provided. I have tried looking at other examples here but struggling to get my head round this. Is this even possible?

Comment: It would be helpful  if you would provide sample data, expected and actual results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Added more information as above @plirkee

Comment: Your source data contains *differences* for certain rows e.g. scores for `print_id=854, dates for `print_id=864`. So you are getting distinct rows. To get your desired result you need to specify *additional rules* for filtering those variations.

Comment: I see you added expected results, however if someone (including myself) wants to try to fix your query, he/she has no data to 'play' with. So you could either simplify your original query or provide sample data of your tables - so that your problem could be replicated and solved ...

Comment: @plirkee and APC, thanks for your responses. Have added more sample data from the two tables. I am new to oracle and this website so apologise for the lack of data or clarity. I feel there is an inner select that is required like APC mentioned, to be able to add additional rules but no idea what to add or even how to.

Comment: Ok. much better ;-)  Now, your join condition for `Table1` and `Table2` is    print_id. You expect to get   `864           4       10-SEP-16  09-MAR-17    96` but `864` also has score `91` so why would you keep only `96`... something is missing in problem description ....or something is wrong in expected results...

Comment: @plirkee the value of 91 is for 854, not 864 if that makes it any better?

Comment: may be ;-)  have you tried any of proposed solutions?

Comment: yes I have tried both variations. @Plirkee think am missing something basic as getting invalid identifier

Comment: Please post test data which matches your desired output. Just saying "it doesn't work" is wasting peoples' time when you haven't provided a clear and accurate set of requirements. Help us to help you.

Comment: I wasn't trying to waste anyone's time or offend anyone. This is my first post where I am seeking help of experts, trying to get my head round Oracle as well as this forum. I have tried to explain so please don't accuse me of wasting time. My desired output is that I would like an out put of `print_id` from `table 1` and for each occurrence of the `print_id' i want it to show the subsequent column with `score` and `timestamp` and also use the `print_id` to link to `table2` and pick out highest value of `segment` and `timestamp` that goes with it. Hope that is clearer.

Comment: Instead of posting more comments please **edit your question** so your desired outcome reflects the posted sample data. We are trying to help you get the answer you want but you have to do your bit to help.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, we don't have the entire picture of your tables and data. However I will try to provide an answer anyway.

The logic is as follows:

First find rows with `max` segments in `table2` (that will be `t2`), then join the resulting  rows (`t2`) with `table1`.

```
with table2 as (
select 416  as print_id,    2 as  segments, sysdate as "TIMESTAMP" from dual 
union all
select 522  as print_id,   5 as  segments, sysdate as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
 union all
select 854  as print_id,   1 as  segments, sysdate as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
 union all
select 854  as print_id,   2 as  segments, sysdate as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
 union all
select 864  as print_id,   3 as  segments, sysdate as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
 union all
select 864  as print_id,   4 as  segments, sysdate as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
),
 table1 as (
select 416  as print_id,   99 as  score, sysdate as "TIMESTAMP" from dual 
union all
select 522  as print_id,   93 as  score, sysdate as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
 union all
select 854  as print_id,   88 as  score, sysdate-1 as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
 union all
select 854  as print_id,   91 as  score, sysdate-1 as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
 union all
select 864  as print_id,   96 as  score, sysdate-2 as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
 union all
select 864  as print_id,   96 as  score, sysdate-2 as "TIMESTAMP" from dual
),
t2 as 
(SELECT a.PRINT_ID , a.segments , a."TIMESTAMP"
FROM Table2 a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.PRINT_ID , MAX(b.segments) segments
    FROM table2 b
    GROUP BY PRINT_ID
) b ON a.PRINT_ID  = b.PRINT_ID AND a.segments = b.segments
)
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.PRINT_ID,
  t2.segments,
  t2."TIMESTAMP",     
  TRUNC(Table1."TIMESTAMP")     AS date1,
  Table1.Score
FROM t2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON t2.PRINT_ID  = Table1.PRINT_ID
WHERE TRUNC(Table1."TIMESTAMP") = trunc(sysdate) 
ORDER BY Table1.PRINT_ID
```

Comment: Yes thanks I think it is pretty much along these lines. At the risk of sounding totally ignorant, could I please ask in the above code, what are values A and B and where are they derived from?

Comment: @shiraztfd `a` is alias for `Table2` in the outer select, and `b` is alias for `Table2` in inner select.  Look at this chunks of sql  (`from table2 a`  `from table2 b`).

Comment: invalid identifier on line 7 `GROUP BY table2.print_id` I have checked the spellings and ensured that no spelling errors. No luck

Comment: @shiraztfd try edited version, I provided sample tables `Table1` and `Table2`, if you want to run against real tables - remove first two blocks from the query.

Comment: Thanks @plirkee I haven't had luck and like the proposed answer below, I get the same error regarding invalid identifier. I have checked and rechecked and not sure what I am doing wrong. I can't copy and paste the exact query due to restrictions with work so have done my best to change names keeping everything simple. I'll continue to work on it. Apologies for wasting your time and thanks for your help.

Comment: @shiraztfd ok! Keep  in mind that the above sql runs "as is" with just copy - pase  (at least on my oracle 11g). Good luck with your task...

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments you have not provided all the business rules required to produce the result set you specify. Unfortunately if you cannot explain what you need we cannot give you an answer, only guesses.

So, here are my guesses:

- from `table1` select print_id, maximum score and corresponding date1
- from `table2` select print_id, maximum segments and corresponding date2

That is, the result set will filter the date columns on the basis of max values of score and segment, rather than chosing score and segments on the basis of latest date.

So, using sub-query factoring syntax and analytical functions to implement the business rules we get:

```
with t1 as (
     select print_id
            , score
            , trunc("TIMESTAMP") as date1
            , row_number() over (partition by print_id order by score desc) as rn
     from table1 )
, t2 as (
     select print_id
            , segments
            , trunc("TIMESTAMP") as date2
            , row_number() over (partition by print_id order by segments desc) as rn
     from table2 )
select t1.print_id
       , t2.segments
       , t1.date1
       , t2.date2
       , t1.score
from t1
     join t2
     on t1.print_id = t2.print_id 
        and t1.rn = t2.rn
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.print_id
```

Comment: what I want to produce is for each unique `print_id` and its corresponding `table1.date`, the `max(segment)` for that `print_id` and its corresponding `table2.date` - is this what you mean by business rules? I have tried implementing both the proposed examples but the query doesn't run

Comment: My answer defines what I mean by business rules: you want one row per `print_id` so what do you want to happen when there is more than one distinct `core` or distinct `date2` for a given `print_id`?

Comment: As for "the query doesn't run" what error do you get? I have run my solution **based on the sample data you have posted** for `table1` and `table2`, and it produces one row for each print_id: 416, 522, 854, 864

Comment: `ORA-00904: "PRINT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 44` does the version of oracle or anything matter in this case?

Comment: `PRINT_ID` is the name of the column you provided. How could it be an invalid identifier? My code will run on Oracle 9i or later.

Comment: I appreciate it is a column name I provided but that is the error I am getting. I have checked all spellings, made sure the tables match up but it is stuck on that error.

Comment: Do your actual tables match the names and structures you have posted here?

Comment: Yes they do. I have checked numerous times. I googled that error and somewhere it said that if the char length of column names is more than 30 it can return that error. The actual name of print ID is longer but it works okay on another query so unsure what isn't adding up.

Comment: "Yes they do." ? But you say "The actual name of print ID is longer" so clearly they don't. You need to post a test case which accurately reflects your situation. As I say **my code runs** against the tables you have posted. So it must be something different in your set-up which you have not included in your question.

Comment: I don;t have enough points to move this to chat so posting here. I mean The actual name in my table is XXX_XXXXX_XXX.XXX_XXXXXXX_XXXXX.PRINT_ID (but I have shortened it here) however when I duplicate your answer or the other suggestion, I am changing names to reflect the correct tables in my query. I assumed this would work. I edited the question to hopefully include this information and make it clearer. Apologies.

Comment: That looks like SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME so is not too long (we're allowed thirty characters for each).

Comment: That's what I thought. It doesn't help that I am fairly new and only learnt SQL in the last three weeks. I'm sure it is a stupid mistake on my part somewhere, I understand the logic in your example and will try and work through it. Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.